# Textarea max-width

Tags: html, css, textarea

I'm having problem with textarea max-width, I need it to not exceed **.table-cell.two** width  when resized, on this example:

[JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/no1lov3sme/t6gzrr7u/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell one">
        <p>small cell</p>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell two">
        <p>textarea cell</p>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
textarea {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
}

.table {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  background: #E2D8C1;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px;
}

.table-cell.two {
  width: 100%;
  background: #DAC082;
}

.table textarea {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px
}
```

*Please do not advise using javascript, needed a pure css solution.*

Comment: Looks fine for me. Describe your problem properly, how you want?

Comment: Sorry, when resizing textarea, I need it to resize height only, width should stay 100%

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Use:

```
textarea { 
   /* will prevent resizing horizontally */
   resize:vertical;
}
```

Comment: This is not supported in IE/Edge and some other major browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=resize

Comment: Edge and all others major browsers support it now.

Answer (score 7):

I have this problem too. The solution is very simple but i spend few hours for experiments... Use this two parameters **at the same time** in textarea element class/#element style definition (90% 30% are example values) :

```
.textarea {
    width:90%;
    max-width:90%;
    max-height:30%;
}
```

Comment: this works, textarea initial width is that of the parent, but then the width shrinks proportionally with parent, as expected.

Answer (score 3):

For default the text area is re sizable. If you want to increase the element width, you can do it by

### HTML

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">Content here</textarea>
```

### CSS

```
max-width: 300px;
max-height:300px
```

Demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6gzrr7u/8/)

In your case you want to fix the `<textarea>` size when the parent does not have a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

For textarea you can set

```
<textarea rows="5"></textarea>
```

and in css

```
textarea { height: auto; }
```