# set maximum height for stretching textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a textarea field. I made it so that when you enter or paste large text, the height of this field automatically increases.

But is it possible to set a minimum height for this field, let's say 50px, and a maximum height, let's say 265px?

```js
$("textarea").each(function () {
  this.setAttribute("style", "height:" + (this.scrollHeight) + "px;overflow-y:hidden;");
}).on("input", function () {
  this.style.height = 0;
  this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea placeholder="Type, paste, cut text here..."></textarea>
```

Comment: What about using the `max-height` or `max-width` css properties?

Comment: Sure, [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and `Math.max()` exist ...

Comment: Both https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65491818/fixing-the-max-height-in-resizable-textarea and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939344/textarea-max-width might be helpful